# COUNT(*) as "column A", GROUP BY "column A", with secondary top of column B

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would you go about getting a query showing the count of different endpoints (column A), with the top consumer (column B) that corresponds to that endpoint?

Here's some example data:

```
+----------+------+
| endpoint | user |
+----------+------+
|  /api/a  | usrA |
|  /api/a  | usrA |
|  /api/a  | usrB |
|  /api/b  | usrA |
|  /api/b  | usrB |
|  /api/b  | usrB |
+----------+------+
```

and what I would like the query results to look like:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| Endpoint | Count | Top User |
+----------+-------+----------+
|  /api/a  |   3   |   usrA   |
|  /api/b  |   3   |   usrB   |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

This is the query I have so far, but it's obviously wrong (the `MAX` function does not do what I thought it did):

```
SELECT
  endpoint as "Endpoint",
  count(*) AS "Count",
  max("user") AS "Top User"
FROM table_a
GROUP BY "Endpoint"
ORDER BY "Count"
```

I think part of my problem here is that I simply don't know the right terminology to ask this question, and if I did, I might be able to google my way to victory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PostgreSQL-specific `DISTINCT ON` clause in an outer query to filter out all but the top users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (endpoint)
       endpoint, "user", c
FROM (SELECT
        endpoint,
        count(*) AS c,
        "user"
      FROM table_a
      GROUP BY endpoint, "user") AS sub
ORDER BY endpoint, c DESC;
```

Comment: This is really good! How would one add a count per endpoint to this?

Comment: Trivial - add `c` to the result columns.

Answer (score 1):

It was more simple than I thought.

This query works correctly:

```sql
SELECT
  endpoint as "Endpoint",
  count(*) AS "Count",
  "user" AS "Top User"
FROM table_a
GROUP BY "Endpoint", "Top User"
ORDER BY "Count"
```

While I was writing this up, it hit me that this was probably what I was looking for. Posting to hopefully help someone else out.

Adding the secondary `GROUP BY` gives a secondary grouping of distinct users and orders them by count. Or at least that's what I think it's doing.

Comment: I thought you wanted only the top user?

Comment: The "top" user per endpoint, not the SQL version of top. I shouldn't have said "top" since it has a special meaning in SQL and is misleading.